# Number Guessing Game with discord.py rewrite

Tags: discord.py

I tried this code, bot says guess but doesn't respond to my guess.

```
@commands.command()
async def game(self, ctx):
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    for guess in range(0, 5):
        await ctx.send('guess')
        Message = await bot.wait_for('message')
        Message = int(Message)
        if Message.cleant_content > number:
            await ctx.send('bigger')
        elif Message.cleant_content < number:
            await ctx.send('smaller')
        else:
            await ctx.send('true')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using cogs, I'd imagine you've got your bot initialised as `self.bot` instead of just `bot`.

Also, you're converting a message *object* to an integer, and trying to access an attribute of an integer named `cleant_content`.

This is how your code should look:

```py
@commands.command()
async def game(self, ctx):
    number = random.randint(0, 100)
    for i in range(0, 5):
        await ctx.send('guess')
        response = await self.bot.wait_for('message')
        guess = int(response.content)
        if guess > number:
            await ctx.send('bigger')
        elif guess < number:
            await ctx.send('smaller')
        else:
            await ctx.send('true')
```

I also changed up a few of the variable names for readability purposes. If you want to, you can add some checks for whether their guess was actually a number or not.

Additionally, I changed what was meant to be `clean_content` to `content` instead, as `clean_content` is completely void of its purpose because you can't convert `<`, `@`, `#`, `!`, `>` and such to an integer, meaning it would error either way. I'm hoping that made some sense.

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)
- [`Message.clean_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content) - Read the difference between `content` and `clean_content` to better understand what I was getting at

Comment: @musta21 Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)

Answer (score 0):

This Is Another Way:

```
@bot.command()
async def game(ctx, *, number=0):
  number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  correct_number = random.choice(number_list)

  if number == correct_number:
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f'Your Number Is {number}', color=0xFF0000)
    embedVar.add_field(name='You Picked The Correct Number! You Won', value="Thanks For Playing!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
  
  else:
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=f'Your Number Is {number}', color=0xFF0000)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Sorry, You Picked The Wrong Number", value="Thanks For Playing")
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did my guess command like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def guess(ctx):

await ctx.send("Guess the number from 1 to 10!")

numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
choice = random.choice(numbers)

answer = await bot.wait_for("message")

if answer.content == choice:
    await ctx.send("You guessed the correct number!")
else:
    await ctx.send(f"You lost! The number was {choice}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `random`:

```
@bot.command()
async def guess(ctx, msg : int = None):
    num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    number = (num_list[randint(0, num_list.__len__()-1)])
    print(number)
    if msg > number:
         await ctx.send("Try again you were to high")
    if msg < number:
        await ctx.send("Try again you were to low")
    if msg == number:
        await ctx.send("You were right")
        await ctx.send(f'The Number is {number}')
```